# inserting captcha in newform SharePoint 2013

Tags: newform

I created a new page in SharePoint Designer 2013 and add new item form on that, now how can I add captcha in that form?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using On-Premise SharePoint.

You can use http://www.recaptcha.net/

1. Download the reCAPTCHA dll from this link http://recaptcha.net/plugins/aspnet/
2. Deploy dll into GAC
3. Update web configuration and add following

   ```
   <SafeControl Assembly="Recaptcha, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c9a3ef27e62a14a" Namespace="Recaptcha" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
   ```
4. Edit New Form aspx page and add

   ```
   <%@ Register Tagprefix="Recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c9a3ef27e62a14a" %>
   ```
5. Now you can use Captcha using below declaration

   ```
   <Recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="idAntiBotReCAPTCHA" runat="server" Theme="clean" PublicKey="CAPTCHA-Public-Key" PrivateKey="CAPTCHA-Private-Key"/>
   ```

For more details refer - http://blogs.salmanghani.info/?p=77

If you want are interested in 3rd party product then try - http://captcha.com/doc/aspnet/sharepoint-captcha.html

**Update**

I just found this - https://recaptchaforsp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you, but the dll link does not working, and codeplex project is deployed captcha for sharepoint 2010

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:aspnetlib-Latest

Comment: That sounds great, but could you please tell me how can I deploy this dll in GAC, I thought copy and paste is enough, but it seems not.

Comment: I got this error:          Could not load file or assembly 'Recaptcha, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c9a3ef27e62a14a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)